# How to combine a timeline with a calendar

Tags: tikz-pgf, calendar, pgfgantt

I'm using the `pgfgantt` package to create a timeline. This is what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \begin{ganttchart}%
            [canvas={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
            hgrid style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
            vgrid={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
            title={draw=none, fill=none},
            title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
            title label anchor={below=-2pt},
            include title in canvas=false,
            bar={draw=none, fill=barblue},
            ]{33}
        \gantttitle[title label anchor={below left=-2pt and -3pt}]{Date:}{0}
        \gantttitlelist[title list options={%
            var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x%
            using "\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\y}"%
        }]{0,...,6}{1} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{7} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 2}{8}{14} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 3}{15}{21} \\
        \end{ganttchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image: Gantt chart]

This is not exactly what I'm expecting. I'd also like to have the date of the current day beside the name of the day (for example: Mon, 1.8.). And this should be repeated for several weeks. For example I'd like to have a timeline for five weeks, starting from today without manually filling in all the dates. I don't know if this is possible with these packages but I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: You accidentally created two unregistered accounts which I merged now together. Please register your account to avoid this in the future. Then you will also be able to comment to all answers of your question(s). Please don't post feedback as "answer" post. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `\pgfcalendar` macro in place of the default `\pgffor` used by `\gantttitlelist` as follows:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\definecolor{barblue}{RGB}{153,204,254}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=1cm]
        \begin{ganttchart}%
            [canvas={fill=none, draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
            hgrid style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
            vgrid={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
            title={draw=none, fill=none},
            title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,
            title label anchor={below=-2pt},
            include title in canvas=false,
            bar={draw=none, fill=barblue},
            ]{33}
        \gantttitle[title label anchor={below left=-2pt and -3pt}]{Date:}{0}
%        \gantttitlelist[title list options={%
%            var=\y, evaluate=\y as \x%
%            using "\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\y}"%
%        }]{0,...,6}{1} \\
        \pgfcalendar{titlecal}{2011-09-21}{2011-10-12}{%
          \gantttitle{\pgfcalendarweekdayshortname{\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday} 
          \pgfcalendarcurrentday}{1}}\\
        \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{7} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 2}{8}{14} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 3}{15}{21} \\
        \end{ganttchart}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first argument (here "titlecal") is a prefix to the names of the nodes created, which isn't of any particular use here, but then the next two are the starting and stopping dates. You can change the actual text that's displayed using the commands in section 57 of the PGF manual.

Comment: Yes, this looks fine. The problem now is that the timline overflows the paper size. Do you know a solution? Maybe some expression to check if there's still enough space and if not start a new line. Well, this could also been done manually for every week but it would be nice if this could be done automatically. Another point – yes, I know it's not part of my original question – is how can I center the timeline on the paper? I tried it using the `center` environment but I didn't succeed.

Comment: `center` seems to work for me provided the timeline fits on the page. But I'm afraid automatically breaking a plot doesn't appear to be trivial. (You might like to pose this as a separate question, since it's quite a different issue: I will have a go if I get a chance, and no doubt so will others!) However, you can squeeze quite a lot more on one page by setting `title label anchor={rotate=90}` and decreasing `x`: e.g., I can fit five weeks happily on an A4 page this way using `x=4mm` and `\scriptsize` font.

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept this answer. Although I have an additional question: When I rotate the labels they get aligned on the top. Is there a possibility to align them on the bottom?

Comment: Does `title label anchor={anchor=base west, rotate=90}` do what you want?

Comment: You could potentially add an `xshift=-10pt` or similar in there too, if you want the bottom of the rotated text to line up with the bottom of the "Date: " text.

Comment: When compiling this example I get the following error: ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgfgantt/fill' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

Comment: The version is not working with 4.0 version.